# Spring Tool Suit 4 doesn't react to 'Ctrl + left click' with class from jar

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

I'm using Spring tool suite 4 and found that the 'Ctrl + left click' does not work with the class from jar but works with myown wirte java file.
And F3 works with both class and java files.
What should I do to fix this.
I used to use 'Ctrl + left click' to locate definitions.

[image: Ctrl+left-click works]

[image: Ctrl+left-click does not work]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug:
https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/205

The bug itself is in the LSP4E implementation and got fixed already. The comments of the issue describe how to update to a snapshot version of LSP4E in order to get the fix immediately. In addition to that the next STS4 version will ship with the fix included.